# Rails - Can't access attribute with dot notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.8 application with a model called Task. In my Task model I have a datetime property called 'complete_date'. When I try to view my complete_date in a view with..

```
<%= @task.complete_date.strftime('%b %e, %Y') %>
```

I get an error saying "undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass". However, the complete_date field is not null. The following query..

```
mysql> select count(*) from tasks where complete_date is null;
```

returns 0 rows. I can retrieve the complete_date, in the same view, with the following code...

```
<% @task.attributes.each_pair do |name, value| %>
    <% if name == "complete_date" %>
      <%= value.strftime('%b %e, %Y') %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly, so it seems the problem is only with accessing the attribute with the dot notation (@task.complete_date). I have listed 'complete_date' as an attr_accessible and an attr_accessor in my Task model. Any idea why I am always getting nil when referencing the complete_date field with @task.complete_date? Thanks.

Comment: Could you open the rails console, load a Task object and check what class it is?? Something like `t = Task.first` and `t.class`

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `attr_accessor :complete_date` ? You should not write it as AR use the method missing to retrieve attributes from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `attr_accessor :complete_date`. Because `attr_accessor` creates two methods (`#complete_date` & `#complete_date=`) and uses the instance variable `@complete_date`, that is nil, because its not filled with the value of the record's attribute. These two methods overrided ActiveRecord attribute accessor methods.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I'm a Rails n00b and thought I was losing my mind!